# Swift - Custom Segues between three UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I use custom segues with animated transitions in my app. And I have a question about navigation between three UIViewControllers. Lets say we have such kind of structure in Storyboard.

[image: here it is].

In words we use it this way:

1. Click *Main[To Scene 1]* calls a *Custom Segue* and goes to *Scene 1*
2. Click *Scene1[To Main]* calls *Unwind Segue* and goes to *Main*
3. Click *Main[To Scene 2]* calls *another Custom Segue* and goes to *Scene 2*
4. Click *Scene2[To Scene 1]* calls *another Custom Segue* and goes to *Scene 1*

And here is the question

4. We click *Scene1[To Main]* and calls **Unwind Segue** and goes to **Scene 2** instead of **Main** (that is ok for this schema but it's not a behavior I want)

So the question is how to achieve such a behavior?

Put an additional Segue from *Scene1[To Main]* to *Main* and check from which ViewController it goes and then call this Segue (for VC *Scene2*) or *Unwind* (for VC *Main*)?

Or there is more elegant way to do this?

Comment: can you explain a little more what exactly the problem is? when i rebuild your hierarchy in xcode everything works as expected!

Comment: hm... I can't understand how it can be... I have on Scene1[To Main] action (unwind): dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil). It goes back to previous view (to Main if we come from Main and To Scene2 if we come from Scene2). What should we do to go from Scene1 to Main even if we come to Scene1 from Scene2?

Comment: 1. question: instead of presenting the viewcontrollers you should wrap your mainviewcontroller inside a navigationcontroller and push scene1, scene2 and so on...
2. question: by calling dismissviewcontroller... you do not really use the technique of unwinding a vc. to do that you have to implement the following method signature in your main vc: - (IBAction)unwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue. then you can ctrl drag from the buttons in scene 1 and scene 2 to the red exit button in interface builder and choose the just created method. did you get me? :)

Comment: The Swift signature for the unwind method in Main is `@IBAction func unwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {`.

Comment: 1. Is this the only such function you have? Only the one in Main VC because it's all you need.  2. You don't need to call `dismissViewControllerAnimated`, when you wire up the function to the exit icon at the top of the view controller, the storyboard will dismiss the VC's for you.

Comment: @AndreSlotta, I have IBAction func unwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) { } and I ctrl drag from button to exit icon and choose it. I'll try it one more time from scratch but empty method does nothing for me, and it's strange. I have an unwind action applied to this button in connection inspector.

Comment: take a look at my demo project. hope it helps: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ap74u761uiyohoc/AACs8J3W8d9iZyszd-acRPcRa?dl=0

Comment: @vacawama, as I said I'll try it one more time. Ok, if it works with empty unwind method it will unwind to Main or to Last (Scene2 VC) I can not understand completely this thing. As I thought it goes to last.

Comment: @AndreSlotta, thank you! everything works fine. We can do this way only using NavigationController?

Comment: It's working for me using modal segues.

Comment: I have only the 1 `@IBAction func unwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {` in the main ViewController.  All unwinds go there as their target.

Comment: should work with and without a navigationcontroller.

Comment: Thank you guys! Will try make it from scratch tomorrow.

Comment: I tried do it now (without NC) and it works with one problem. When I click on Scene1[To Main] after I come here from Scene2 it firstly quickly go to Scene2 and then to Main. Why this happens?

Comment: Maybe you still call dismiss programmatically?

Comment: No dismiss function calls.

Comment: Why this is working this way?

Answer (score 1):

1.why don't you embed your initial view controller into a navigation controller...and save you the segues...and you can just push the Back button..

go to your storyboard...click on your main view controller, select editor, go to "embed in" and select navigation controller.

2. if you don't have a navigation bar...and if unwind segue is giving you some issues, just create another segue from your scene 1, back to your main, and then call that segue on your Scene One "to Main" button.

and make sure both of your unwind segues don't have the exact same name..